# What is the best practice when tagging a question: explicit as much as possible or, contrariwise, use suggestion?

Tags: discussion, tags

To put it in other words:

Is it better to tag a question about some jquery issue with

- [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) and [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) (explicit) or
- [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) (suggests javascript) ?

Is it better to tag a question about some django orm behavior with

- [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) and [django-orm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-orm) (explicit) or
- [django-orm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-orm) (suggests django and therefore python) ?

Are there any straightforward guidelines for that ?

Comment: Sorry if the title isn't crystal clear: feel free to clarify it if you find the right words.

Comment: This question has a great answer here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18879/165786

Answer (score 2):

People use the tags to find your question, so the tags should be choosen to fit that task.

Will someone that just knows Python but has no special knowledge about Django likely be able to help with the answer to your question? If so, add [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), otherwise don't.

So if you have problems using Django Api call, probably knowing Python doesn't help much. You really have to be familiar with Django to be able to help and many people know Python but have no knowledge about Django. So adding [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) probably won't be useful.

In the case of [django-orm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-orm) the question is the same: Will somebody who knows Django likely be familiar with Django's ORM? Here the answer is probably yes, I assume. If you use Django you probably use the ORM and also there probably aren't many dedicated Django ORM experts that just know that part of Django. So [django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django) would be the main and most important tag here.
But adding [django-orm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/django-orm) still adds value, because it indicates the specific topic and helps people to find things that interest them specifically.

It's also the same from the point of view of someone searching for an answer. When you have problems with the Abc() call in Django you will probably not search for "python abc" but rather for "django abc". If you still get too many unrelated results you might add "orm" to narrow it down.

Comment: Another perspective: Would everyone who has `python` on their ignored tags list want to ignore questions about Django?