# Generic tag used while framework has been used?

Tags: support, tags

Users tend to "over-tag" their questions, like #java #jsf #jpa #html #css but this is wrong in my view (I have suggested tag edits to some posts of this type, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20666406)).

For example, the tag #java is generic (JavaSE, EE, ME all together) while #jsf is a MVC/MPC framework written in Java. Now users have some Java code (e.g. backing beans or entities), JSF views (which will generate output in HTML) and some JPA-related code like entities with annotations in their question and happily tag it with many tags.

To continue the example, JSF tags like `h:link` are surely producing HTML code but you should not think that way, they are components that you put in your views. So the #html (and also #css) tags are wrong here as they are for (IMO) generic HTML/CSS questions and not JSF-related.

My question here is: **Is this proper usage of generic tags or is a bit "over-tagging"? And are my edits then correct or oversensitive?**

My **suggestion to improve the situtation**: #java tag says "this is anything about Java", while #java-generic says "only generic Java has been used". When it comes to this language, tags like #java-se #java-ee and #java-me may help narrowing down your tags (not to broad like #java is) and alerting more the right people.

Comment: Could you provide links to this questions?

Comment: So, if I have subscription on [tag:php] I will not see this question 'cause you has removed this tag, right?

Comment: @Suvitruf yes, you can then subscribe on #laravel for example as well.

Comment: @Roland but I want to see all [tag:php] questions. If you deletes [tag:php] from those question, I have to sub on all php frameworks tags.

Comment: A tag is meant so a question will be found by an expert. Your tagging should strive to bring the right eyes to the question and it should prevent that experts that have no interest in that question will see it. This sometimes means you need to add a generic tag while in other cases adding a generic tag might have an adverse effect.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51982832/wordpress-echo-post-count A WordPress-related question (see function invocations to `wp_count_posts()` which is no generic PHP function). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php < No framework whatsoever has been used/questioned. The `php` tag is okay here.

Comment: "which is no generic PHP function" but it's still a `php` code, even though it's not native php function.

Comment: @rene exactly my point, what is the questioner asking about? Framework- / library-related (but still with a few generic code parts) or is no framework/library being used at all?

Comment: @Suvitruf Frameworks today are very complex and with generic PHP knowledge you sometimes cannot get far (see Typo3 for a really good example). Sure they are "all" (Laravel, Typo3, CI, CakePHP, ...) written in PHP but you use a framework/library here.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: Hmm, this thing is not easy as it seems. On one hand you want to read all #php related posts (even you will face some said frameworks which are written in that language and have grown complex, pure PHP knowledge may not fully help you then, example Typo3). But on the other hand, you may not wish to read anything about frameworks when you follow generic tags.

Comment: An idea: #php remains as "this is about PHP" tag, while #php-generic should be used when the question is not involving any framework/library (means plain language). Same with #java (all editions, including JSF/JSP/Spring/Groovy) and #java-generic (e.g. a question about `java.util.List`-related things.

Comment: @Roland: Also keep in mind that frameworks might not exist in one language only. For example, Qt, OpenGL, ... are not inherently bound to a language. Tagging it with the language is absolutely necessary to know if you can even understand the question.

Comment: @BDL such questions I would **not** touch. OpenGL is language-independent as there are tons of languages supporting it, like C/C++/C#, Java, Python, PHP and many more.

Answer (score 3):

This, albeit in different guises, is a recurring issue. However, that you have felt obliged to ask here whether your actions were correct is strong indication that they were not. When not reasonably sure users should not be acting first and then considering afterwards. So, your edit suggestions were not correct because edit suggestions should not be made speculatively. That is so even if the suggestions are approved.

It *feels wrong to me* is shared with other users but is not a case for changing what others have posted. Different tags follow different conventions and when in any doubt tagging should be left to those with a combined score across the examples you gave that is considerably higher than your 7 or so.

I did ask about this myself, a long time ago, on a different site, and a mod suggested "stuffing". (It was clearly more an indication of personal preference than a diktat.) Totally irrelevant and highly peripheral tags should *not* be included but in general "the more the merrier".

If you disagree please at least support your view with more than "feels wrong".

*users have some Java code, JSF views and some JPA-related code in their question* so, if say uncertain where their problem arises, why should they *not* apply all three?

[Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/354933/1505120)
[Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251815/what-is-the-best-practice-when-tagging-a-question-explicit-as-much-as-possible)

Comment: Asking/Discussing here when you note that others are not happy with your actions is at least better than just doing stuff and go to complete silence and refuse to discuss it when someone asks/disagrees.

Comment: @pnuts I have updated my question and removed the "feels wrong" term.

Comment: @BDL Thank you, I know what I'm doing but I was not entirely sure to move on like this. So I better ask (having already changed a few which is not a big impact) before I continue on the wrong path, like "Am I doing this right? Is this really okay?"

Comment: @Roland: What you did is exactly what you should've done. You did something, and asked for feedback when you weren't sure how to proceed. The comment was actually not targeted at you but to the answer author.

Comment: @pnuts thank you for pointing some things out. I have completed more my example in an attempt to explain my view.

Comment: @pnuts Your answer was helpful and answers my question even when the topic is not so easy to decide. In next edits, I will be more careful (and I was already thinking a little about it).